# react native access variable outside componentDidMount fuction

Tags: react-native

Thanks in advance

I need to access currentPostion out of getCurrentPosition function in react native and i am beginner in react native.

Code :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    coords: [],
    currentPostion: ""
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({'currentPostion':initialPosition});
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
  );
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state)); 
}
```

Help Me !!!

Answer (score 1):

`currentPosition` will be  undefined initially and since its inside componentDidmount.. it will be updated at a later stage. You need to wait till the values are updated and then access them. U can use a loading symbol to wait till the state is updated and once its not `undefined` u can access the values.

`if(this.state.currentPosition === ""){
      return(
      <ActivityIndicator  />
      )
    }
    return (
      <Component lat={this.state.currentPosition} />
    );`

donot forget to import Activity indicator